# Safest way to export personal files, wipe PC clean, and Import personal files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, virus

I want to wipe my PC clean incase I have any malware, trojans, or viruses.
I am planning to store all my personal files on a external HD via USB, however  am wondering if its possible that the virus could jump from the infected machine to the external HD whilst I am exporting and if there is a way to detect this?

After I wipe my PC clean and install a new OS, what is the safest way to import my files from my external HD? Is it possible that if a virus/trojan did transfer itself to the external HD, can it infect my newly installed OS just by plugging in the external HD to the USB port?

What should I look out for and is there any safer ways to go about this?

I am using Windows 8.1 pro

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you could stop the scenario, and all preceding scenarios by having a decent AV installed. Are you asking a theoretical question in the context of your anti-malware being hopelessly incompetent against a highly intelligent 'super'-virus?

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely every chance that a piece of malware will attach to data files. There are a variety that do so.

The safest approach is to export the files then format the system drive and reboot from a read-only operating system such as Knoppix on a CD or read-only USB. Use a live cd that has an antivirus tool installed and check the data disk.

When you are sure it is clean, re-install an OS on the main disk. Install anti-virus and anti-malware tools, reboot then reconnect the data drive and copy the data back again.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to viruses, the rule of thumb is this:

Files need to be executed to be dangerous. The obvious dangerous file type is .exe, but it also includes some not so obvious ones, such as excell macros, vb scripts, and other file types that contain code to be executed.

On the other hand, this means that certain files can be considered safe. Examples include .txt, .avi, .mp3, .jpeg, and whatnot, as these do not actually contain any executable code, but just data to be read and desplayed in various shapes and forms.

The third category is a bit of a gray area. This involves archives, compressed or otherwise. You will have to look at these individually, and use your best judgement based on their contents.

To ensure a clean rebuild of your system, once you've copied out everything you want to keep, you need to nuke the entire drive with its remaining contents. Viruses these days are tricky and can even hide in the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record), so ensure that you don't just do a format, but also completely wipe the drive for partitions.

As for the migration, your safest bet is to assume that all executable files (the first category) are infected. If you need them, reacquire them from a trusted source once you're getting up and running again.

And to answer your question about infection: Yes, it can. First you need to copy out what you can salvage, then wipe, then reinstall. There should be no direct contact between your old installation and any executable files on the new system, this includes any executable files on a USB drive that you want to keep.